# Proper way to concatenate mixed type variables WITHOUT using f statement

Tags: python, string, variables, concatenation

What would be the proper way to combine something like this?

```
thisID=12345
myVar= '<!',thisID,'!>'
```

Expected result: <! 12345 !>

Python is using the commas to convert into a tuple, but I need them to be treated as concatenators instead

EDIT:

My version didnt have f statement, so in case anyone else is needing a similar concat without using f, this worked for me

```
thisNewID=12345

myVar="<! {thisNewID} !>".format(thisNewID=thisNewID)
```

Comment: Sounds like you want string formatting `myVar = f'<! {thisID} !>'`

Comment: Is this dependent on python version?  I am getting a syntax error but I doubt its wrong since there are 2 identical replies

Comment: For older versions of python, `myVar = '<! {} !>'.format(thisID)` (for even older version, you might need `{0}` instead of `{}`).

Comment: I am actually using this inside of sublime text api and its on python 3.3 and give syntax error.  Also the .format(myVar) didnt work either...

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the
[intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).  
Any tutorial on Python strings includes how to convert between string and numeric types, as well as string concatenation.  Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing tutorials and documentation.

Comment: Im being downvoted and tried to delete this.  Why would a system make it difficult to delete unwanted information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a more complete answer that I would have appreciated more than all the downvotes.

The f statement does not work on every version of python.
Newer versions can use

```
thisNewID=12345
myVar= f'<! {thisID} !>'
```

My version happened to be 3.3 and that did NOT work, but below syntax did.

```
myVar="<! {thisNewID} !>".format(thisNewID=thisNewID)
```

To properly answer this question, an experienced person would first have to ask what version, since this IS version specific syntax.

Comment: To clarify, the initial post didn't specify "without f statement". I would recommend deleting answers that include the usage of the phrase I specifically asked to avoid. It was my error to post wrong, but the current state of this posts Q & A is not aligned due to answers rolling in literally seconds after.

Answer (score 1):

The easier approach would probably to use an f-string:

```py
myVar= f'<! {thisID} !>'
```

Comment: this is the easiest most up to date approach  if you have f statement in your version of python, but its worth noting my edit in the OP for alternatives when it doesnt work, as was the case for me

Answer (score 0):

```
thisID=12345
myVar= '<!'+str(thisID)+'!>'
```

Answer (score -1):

There are several ways to do it.
I recommend to use str(int) + 'string'.
FYI, you can have a look at this.
https://www.askpython.com/python/string/python-concatenate-string-and-int